# Print Int if value is higher than 0

Tags: c

I made a programm that splits a number into banknotes. I wanted to know to to only output integers when the value is more than 0. (I hope the german sentences are not a problem)

```
int main() {

int Gesamtbetrag;
int hundert;
int fuenfzig;
int zwanzig;
int zehn;
int fuenf;
int zwei;
int eins;

// Input vom User.
printf("Geben Sie einen Geldbetrag ein:\n");
scanf( "%d", &Gesamtbetrag);

// Loop wenn die Zahl größer als 400 ist.
while (Gesamtbetrag > 400)  {
    printf("Geben Sie einen Geldbetrag ein:\n");
    scanf( "%d", &Gesamtbetrag);
}

// Rechnungen für die Anzahl der Banknoten.
hundert = (Gesamtbetrag - (Gesamtbetrag % 100)) / 100;
fuenfzig = (Gesamtbetrag - (hundert * 100)) / 50;
zwanzig = ((Gesamtbetrag - (hundert * 100)) - (fuenfzig * 50)) / 20;
zehn = (((Gesamtbetrag - (hundert * 100)) - (fuenfzig * 50)) - (zwanzig * 20)) / 10;
fuenf = (((Gesamtbetrag - ((hundert * 100)) - (fuenfzig * 50)) - (zwanzig * 20)) - (zehn * 10)) / 5;
zwei = ((((Gesamtbetrag - ((hundert * 100)) - (fuenfzig * 50)) - (zwanzig * 20)) - (zehn * 10)) - (fuenf * 5)) / 2;
eins = ((((Gesamtbetrag - ((hundert * 100)) - (fuenfzig * 50)) - (zwanzig * 20)) - (zehn * 10)) - (fuenf * 5)) - (zwei * 2) / 1;


// Ausgabe der Banknoten.
printf("100 Euro Scheine: %d\n", hundert);
printf("50 Euro Scheine:  %d\n", fuenfzig);
printf("20 Euro Scheine:  %d\n", zwanzig);
printf("10 Euro Scheine:  %d\n", zehn);
printf("5 Euro Scheine:   %d\n", fuenf);
printf("2 Euro Muenze:    %d\n", zwei);
printf("1 Euro Muenze:    %d\n", eins);




return 0;
```

}

Comment: So, check `if` the value is greater than zero before doing the `printf`? I don't understand what the difficulty is here.

Comment: if (hundert > 0)
{
    printf("100 Euro Scheine: %d\n", hundert);
}

Sounds like what you need for the hundreds, and so on...